# Convert Hardcoded Integers to Enums in VB using Visual Studio

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, enums

I have inherited some code from someone else, and I have implemented a few `Enums` to keeps various coding schemes straight.  Is there a way in Visual Studio 2017 put some automation behind this?  I am sure I will have to do some work manually, as I don't expect VS to know what `Enum` each integer should be, but it would be VERY helpful if I don't have to keep cross referencing values manually.

Comment: What automation are you talking about? I don´t think that there is any. How should it even work? E.g. if you want to replace parameter types of methods how should an automation know that `foo(int i)` should be replaced with `foo(YourEnum i)`?

Comment: I was hoping for something like the encapsulation feature.  If such a thing existed, I would expect to have to go to each int manually and tell VS which enum I want, but if I have 30 items in 4 different enums, it could save a lot of time and possible errors.  But I knew it was a long shot.

Comment: Oh, this is interesting but I don't think it's possible in VS. Maybe look into [Resharper](https://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/)... still not sure they even do it.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I did:  It was not as quick and clean as I would have liked, but at least I didn't have to keep cross referencing.  I changed all my enum elements to `o1`, `o2`...  (The 'o' is because an Enum element cannot start with a digit.)  Then I was able to paste `MyEnumType.o` in front of all the appropriate Integers.  Then I went back to the Enum and right-click -> "Rename..."ed each element back to the appropriate name.

Not very elegant, but effective.